# Google Apps + PHP mail() problem

Tags: php, sendmail, email, g-suite

When I send emails using PHP's mail() function from my web app I can deliver e-mails successfully to any e-mail address except to my own Google Apps e-mail account, which happens to be on the same domain the web app is on.

I've read http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55299 which seems to be my problem, but I don't understand what it's telling me to do. I've also looked at http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/google-apps-mail-problem-139337.html but I'm not sure if that's specific to cpanel or not.

I'm on a VPS with Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy Herron.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most MTAs (mail servers) will not lookup MX records if the local server has email setup for the domain, they will instead deliver locally. Turn off email locally for this domain (or I believe there might be a setting in cpanel to force DNS lookups) and your emails should start working.

Comment: Do you know how to do this through the shell? I don't have cpanel :-(

Thanks

Comment: which mailserver are you using? Likely to be either postfix, qmail or exim

Comment: I'm using sendmail

Comment: go into each file that  
`grep -R -l "the_email_hostname" /var/mail/*` returns and delete the entry for the hostname.

Comment: Hmm, there;s nothing in /var/mail but a file called www-data which appears to be a log of delivered e-mails

Comment: do a `locate sendmail.cf` and then run the above command again substituting /var/mail for whichever directory it returns.

Comment: Thanks for the help I really appreciate it! Unfortunately I haven't got it working yet but I'm pretty sure we were on the right track. 
I asked for some help from my VPS host to get sendmail to not deliver locally, and they are handling it at the moment. Thanks!